# How to update values from one where condition to other where condition on same table and column using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to update a column values on different where conditions.
below is the example

```
ID,  Product,   MonthID,  Rate
1 ,     a,      201610,    13
2 ,     a,      201611,    22
3 ,     b,      201610,    29
4 ,     b,      201611,    14

SELECT rate 
FROM dbo.sales 
WHERE monthid = 201610

ID,  Product,  MonthID,  Rate
 1,     a,     201610,    13
 3,     b,     201610,    29
```

I get rate values as above. Now I want to see these rate column values in the same table on different `monthid` condition as below

```
SELECT rate 
FROM dbo.sales 
WHERE monthid = 201611
```

**After update Result:**

```
ID,  Product,  MonthID,   Rate
 2,     a,     201611,     13
 4,     b,     201611,     29
```

**Final Table:**

```
ID,  Product,   MonthID,   Rate
 1,     a,      201610,     13
 2,     a,      201611,     13
 3,     b,      201610,     29
 4,     b,      201611,     29
```

Is it possible to update rate values from one where condition to another where condition?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update s
set rate = (select rate from dbo.sale where idmonth = 201610 and product = a.product )
from dbo.sales s 
where idmonth = 201611
```

only works when you have just one recored for each product in each month.

Answer (score 0):

This could helps to update rate values.

```
update s1
    set s1.rate = s2.rate
from sales s2 (nolock)
inner join sales s1
    on s1.MonthID = s2.MonthID + 1 and s1.Product = s2.Product
where s2.MonthID = 201610
```

Answer (score 0):

Create V1(View in sql) :
SELECT        id, Product, MonthID, Rate
FROM            dbo.tb1
WHERE        (MonthID = 201610)

Create V2(View in sql) :
SELECT        id, Product, MonthID, Rate
FROM            dbo.tb1
WHERE        (MonthID = 201611)

Create V3(View in sql) :
SELECT        dbo.V1.id, dbo.V1.Product, dbo.V1.MonthID, dbo.V1.Rate, dbo.V2.id AS id2, dbo.V2.Product AS Product2, dbo.V2.MonthID AS MonthID2, dbo.V2.Rate AS Rate2
FROM            dbo.V1 INNER JOIN
                         dbo.V2 ON dbo.V1.Product = dbo.V2.Product
GROUP BY dbo.V1.id, dbo.V1.Product, dbo.V1.MonthID, dbo.V1.Rate, dbo.V2.id, dbo.V2.Product, dbo.V2.MonthID, dbo.V2.Rate

id  Product MonthID Rate    id2 Product2    MonthID2    Rate2
1     a      201610  13      2    a          201611      22
3     b      201610  29      4    b          201611      14